# Twig sum row above the summerisation

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm kinda new to twig and I know it is possible to add up values in a template and collect them in a variable. But what i actually need is to show the summerised value in the template before I sum up them. I need something like slots in the old symfony. Or in php I could do this by ob_start(). It is possible in twig somehow?

I whould like it something like this.

```
sum is: {{ sum }} {# obviously it is 0 right here, but i want the value from the calculation #}

{# some content.. #} 

{% set sum = 0 %}

{% for r in a.numbers}

   {% set sum = sum + r.number %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why are you not doing the calculations in the controller? Twig is really only suppose to be used to display the calculated data. In MVC your views arent really suppose to be running the calculations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can extend twig by adding extra filters http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

In your case, you can use array_sum function:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('sum', 'array_sum'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

if you don't want to use the controller and want to do the summing in twig then try using the set command:

```
{# do loop first and assign whatever output you want to a variable #}
{% set sum = 0 %}    
{% set loopOutput %}               
    {% for r in a.numbers}            
       {% set sum = sum + r.number %}        
    {% endfor %}    
{% endset %}

 sum is: {{ sum }} 

{# some content.. #} 

{{ loopOutput }}
```

I assume the loop was in a specific place because it is intended to output something into the template, this allows you to rearrange the load order while still displaying as you want.

Answer (score 4):

**As of Twig 1.41 and 2.10 a `reduce` filter was added**

> The `reduce` filter iteratively reduces a sequence or a mapping to a single
>   value using an arrow function, so as to reduce it to a single value. The arrow
>   function receives the return value of the previous iteration and the current
>   value of the sequence or mapping:
>
> ```
> {% set numbers = [1, 2, 3] %}
>
> {{ numbers|reduce((carry, v) => carry + v) }}
> {# output 6 #}
> ```
>
> The `reduce` filter takes an `initial` value as a second argument:
>
> ```
> {{ numbers|reduce((carry, v) => carry + v, 10) }}
> {# output 16 #}
> ```
>
> Note that the arrow function has access to the current context.

**Arguments:**

- `array`: The sequence or mapping
- `arrow`: The arrow function
- `initial`: The initial value

---

Ref: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/reduce.html

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to this would be to use the MVC standard and let your controller do the sum calculations for you.

```
//In your controller file

public function yourControllerAction(){
    //how ever you define $a and $content would go here

    $sum = 0;
    foreach($objects as $a)
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($a->numbers as $r){
            $sum += $r->number;
        }
        $a->sum = $sum;
    }


    return array(
        'objects' => $objects,
        'content' => $content
    );
}
```

Now you have the sum variable already calculated to use in your twig file:

```
{# twig file #}
{% for a in objects %}
    sum is: {{ a.sum }}
    {% for number in a.numbers %}
        {{number}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{# some content.. #}
```

Comment: I pass an array of objects to the template which contains the numbers. Something like this:

Array( 0 => Object1, 1 => Object2) etc. These objects contain the numbers in some collections. I thought if I could add up the numbers in the template then I didn't have to go throught this array of objects with some complicated logic with like 4 foreachs.

It just had been simpler to me, but possibly I'll go with your suggestions and sum these numbers up in the Controller.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Just something came into my mind when I started implementing your answer. I need this sums grouped by objects so that when I list the objects I can easily handle the sums for the objects.

I kinda want something like this: $obj->numbers is an array which i list out and $obj->sum could be the summed up value.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give an example based on your object structure. If you add a sum property to your object then you could set it using the above method. then your twig implementation would look something like i have up there as well.

Answer (score 2):

I build a twig extension to achieve this. The target is to give the array and the property to a twig extension and calculate the result.

First, register the service:

```
affiliate_dashboard.twig.propertysum:
    class: AffiliateDashboardBundle\Service\PropertySum
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then implement the TwigExtension:

namespace AffiliateDashboardBundle\Service;

```
class PropertySum extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('propertySum', array($this, 'propertySum')),
        );
    }

    public function propertySum($collection, $property)
    {
        $sum = 0;
        $method = 'get' . ucfirst($property);

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            if (method_exists($item, $method)) {
                $sum += call_user_func(array($item, $method));
            }
        }

        return $sum;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'property_sum';
    }
}
```

After that, you can easily calculate the sum of a property of an specific collection. Also working with doctrine relations. Example usage:

```
{{ blogpost.affiliateTag.sales|propertySum('revenue') }}
```

Done!