# sum each array value

Tags: arrays, twig

i have an array and  want to sum their value for each index. how can i do that ?

```
sortiment: shoe1,AD12,Nike,0,1,2,0,3,2,0,0,1
```

so i split the row sortiment into

```
{% set sortimentArray = key.sortiment|split(',') | slice(3)%}
```

now i only have the numbers saved in sortimentArray. how can i sum them ?

```
    {% for key in sortimentArray %}

    {# code to sum the values and save them in a variable #}
    {% set allIndexValues = sortimentArray[0] + 1 %}

    {% endfor%}

    {{ allIndexValues }}
```

this doesnt work and i jsut made it up, can anyone help with the theory ? in this case a value of 9 should come out

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Twig sum row above the summerisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933753/twig-sum-row-above-the-summerisation). You can use the `reduce` filter to easily sum your values

Comment: The answer from previous person already solved my problem thanks, it got deleted for some reason but i got my answer

Answer (score 0):

Some one gave me this solution but delete his answer. Thanks to him this worked.

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for value in key.sortiment|split(',')|slice(3) %}
{% set total = total + value %}
{% endfor %}
{{ total }}
```

Comment: Deleted it cause somebody already linked to a duplicate solutions.

Comment: ive already watched the recommended duplicate solutions,  the other one did not help

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare your `allIndexValues` variable outside the for-loop, otherwise this variable only has a scope *inside* the for-loop and is undefined outside the loop.

This would actually throw  an error that `variable "allIndexValues" does not exist` when you enable the debug mode in `twig` and try to access it outside the loop.

The proper for-loop in twig is defined as `{% for value in array %}` so not sure why you are referencing `sortimentArray[0]` as you can the get correct value in the variable `key`

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% set total = 0 %}
    {% for value in item.sortiment|split(',')|slice(3) %}
        {% set total = total + value %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    Total: {{ total }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/mame3w)