# Trying to add multiple invoices for a total

Tags: php, twig

I am VERY new to twig. So new that I have no clue what im doing to be honest lol.  I have the following code that loops the information into rows.. What I am trying to figure out is what is the correct twig or what not to add all the "invoice.total" from each row it lists to total out to a final total? The "invoice.total" could list say 2 - 5 unpaid invoices.

In the code it will display say 3 unpaid invoices in rows.. I am trying to get the total of those invoices to display in one spot as a quick glance this is how much you completely owe.

```
<td align="right" class="text-danger fw-bold"><b>{{ 'Students Unpaid Invoice Number'|trans }}</b></td>
                            <th>{{ 'Amount'|trans }}</th>
                            <th>{{ 'Issued on'|trans }}</th>
                            <th>{{ 'Status'|trans }}</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                   {% set invoices = admin.invoice_get_list({ "status":"unpaid", 'per_page': '100', 'client_id': client.id }) %}
                        {% for invoice in invoices.list %}
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <a href="{{ '/invoice/manage'|alink }}/{{ invoice.id }}">{{ invoice.serie_nr }}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ mf.currency_format( invoice.total, invoice.currency) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ invoice.created_at|format_date }}</td>                            
                            <td>{% if invoice.status == 'unpaid' %}
                                <span class="badge bg-danger me-1"></span>
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ mf.status_name(invoice.status) }} </td>
                           </tr>
                        {% else %}
                        <tr>
                         <td colspan="6">{{ 'The list is empty'|trans }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}</td>
                        </tr>
```

I know the twig math would be such as {{ 1 + 1 }} and it would add what is listed.  {{ invoice.total + invoice.total }} but that will only add the total from that line twice and not add all invoice.totals together.

Comment: Did you do some research?  For example: [Twig sum row above the summerisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933753/twig-sum-row-above-the-summerisation)

Comment: You should do as less logic/programming as possible in templates. Do it in the controller and assign it to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `set` statement to initialize a variable outside of your loop, and then increment it inside the loop to keep a running total.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="text-danger fw-bold"><b>{{ 'Students Unpaid Invoice Number'|trans }}</b></td>
        <th>{{ 'Amount'|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ 'Issued on'|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ 'Status'|trans }}</th>
    </tr>
    {% set total = 0 %} {# Initialize the total variable #}
    {% set invoices = admin.invoice_get_list({ "status":"unpaid", 'per_page': '100', 'client_id': client.id }) %}
    {% for invoice in invoices.list %}
        {% set total = total + invoice.total %} {# Increment the total by the invoice total #}
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <a href="{{ '/invoice/manage'|alink }}/{{ invoice.id }}">{{ invoice.serie_nr }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ mf.currency_format( invoice.total, invoice.currency) }}</td>
            <td>{{ invoice.created_at|format_date }}</td>                            
            <td>
                {% if invoice.status == 'unpaid' %}
                    <span class="badge bg-danger me-1"></span>
                {% endif %}
                {{ mf.status_name(invoice.status) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">{{ 'The list is empty'|trans }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>{{ 'Total Amount Owed'|trans }}:</strong></td>
        <td>{{ mf.currency_format(total, invoice.currency) }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you got the answer feel free to accept